# Can I create/edit .jsp files with Microsoft Expression Web?

Tags: java, jsp, dreamweaver, microsoft-expression-web

I can't afford to use Dreamweaver and I am wondering if Microsoft Expression Web can create web pages that use .jsp to interact with Java code ?

I know that Microsoft are not great friends with Java but, have they really ignored it completely?

Comment: I suggest you to use Eclipse instead. Just a sugestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Microsoft Visual Studio Express. Also, see [THIS](http://danskousenandfamily.blogspot.com/2006/12/make-visual-studio-your-java-and-jsp.html) tutorial to include syntax highlighting, auto formatting, etc. while editing .jsp files in Visual Studio.